# redirect not working with 'REQUEST_METHOD'

Tags: codeigniter

On my login controller, I am trying `($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST')` for submitting form instead of codeigniter form_validation

But when I use **redirect()** it does not redirect.

**Question:** Why does the redirects not working when submitting form with `($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD')` and what is the best solution to get it to work.

**Update:** Does not seem to submit the form because I use `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';` Instead of `$config['uri_protocol']  = 'REQUEST_URI';`

But need to use `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';`

**Routes.php**

```
$route['route=common/login'] = 'admin/common/login/index';
$route['route=common/dashboard&token=(:any)'] = 'admin/common/dashboard/index';
$route['route=common/logout&token=(:any)'] = 'admin/common/logout/index';
```

**Config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project-cms/admin/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';
```

**Login Controller**

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends MX_Controller {

    public function index()
    {

        if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') {

            $token = md5(mt_rand());

            $url_token = '&token=' . $token;

            echo "working";

            //redirect('index.php?route=common/dashboard' . $url_token);

            //$this->response->redirect($this->url->link('common/dashboard', $url_token, 'SSL'));
        }

        $data['action'] = $this->url->link('common/login', '', 'SSL');

        $this->load->view('template/common/login', $data);
    }
}
```

**Login View**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo $action;?>">

<input type="text" name="username" />

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

**Version:** Codeigniter 3 & XAMPP With Windows 7

Comment: Its an invalid way to define routes. http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`REQUEST_METHOD`** has nothing to do with your redirection issue.
You are using a wrong method to define routes.

```
$route['common/login'] = 'admin/common/login/index';
$route['common/dashboard/(:any)'] = 'admin/common/dashboard/index/$1';
$route['common/logout/(:any)'] = 'admin/common/logout/index/S1';
```

And you will get your token (in your controllers) as,

```
public function index($token)
{
    echo $token;
}
```

And change your login controllers as,

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Login extends MX_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') {
            $token = md5(mt_rand());
            redirect('common/dashboard/' . $url_token);
        }
        $data['action'] = $this->url->link('common/login', '', 'SSL');
        $this->load->view('template/common/login', $data);
    }
}
```